# Unmarshalling nested XML tags

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

My goal is to unmarshalling XML file to one Java object.
My XML looks like:

```
<root>
   <info1>
   <info2>
   <info3>
       <nested1>
           <nested2>
               <info4>
               <info5>
           <nested2>
       <nested1>
<root>
```

I receive information only from info1-info3.
BusinessOperationEvent have all XMLElements from XML file.
Parser class:

```
public class Parser {

public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Parser.class.getClassLoader();
        File xml = new File(classLoader.getResource("XML.xml").getFile());

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(BusinessOperationEvent.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        BusinessOperationEvent event = (BusinessOperationEvent) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
        System.out.println(event);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error unmarshalling XML");
    }
}
}
```

BusinessOperationEvent is Java object to collect information from XML:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "SrvPutBusinessOperationEventNf")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BusinessOperationEvent {

@XmlElement(name = "RqUID")
private String rqUID;
@XmlElement(name = "RqTm")
private String rqTm;
@XmlElement(name = "sPName")
private String sPName;
@XmlElement(name = "SystemId")
private String systemId;
@XmlElement(name = "Method")
private String method;
@XmlElement(name = "BusinessProcess")
private String businessProcess;
@XmlElement(name = "Operation")
private String operation;
@XmlElement(name = "Step")
private String step;
@XmlElement(name = "SourceModule")
private String sourceModule;
@XmlElement(name = "Id")
private String id;
@XmlElement(name = "EventDate")
private String eventDate;
@XmlElement(name = "SendDate")
private String sendDate;
@XmlElement(name = "ActionCallInfo")
private String actionCallInfo;
@XmlElement(name = "ActivityRepCallInfo")
private String activityRepCallInfo;
@XmlElement(name = "AccountEPKId")
private String accountEPKId;
@XmlElement(name = "AccountCRMId")
private String accountCRMId;
@XmlElement(name = "CallId")
private String сallId;
@XmlElement(name = "CalledFromNum")
private String calledFromNum;
@XmlElement(name = "AppealName")
private String appealName;
@XmlElement(name = "CallbackPhone")
private String callbackPhone;
@XmlElement(name = "EndDate")
private String endDate;
@XmlElement(name = "Comment")
private String comment;
@XmlElement(name = "Result")
private String result;
@XmlElement(name = "CreatorFullName")
private String creatorFullName;
@XmlElement(name = "EmployeeId")
private String employeeId;
@XmlElement(name = "CRMCCQuestionInfo")
private String crmccQuestionInfo;
@XmlElement(name = "ServiceRequestInfo")
private String serviceRequestInfo;
@XmlElement(name = "ActionMeetingInfo")
private String actionMeetingInfo;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "BusinessOperationEvent{" +
            "rqUID='" + rqUID + '\'' +
            ", rqTm='" + rqTm + '\'' +
            ", sPName='" + sPName + '\'' +
            ", systemId='" + systemId + '\'' +
            ", method='" + method + '\'' +
            ", businessProcess='" + businessProcess + '\'' +
            ", operation='" + operation + '\'' +
            ", step='" + step + '\'' +
            ", sourceModule='" + sourceModule + '\'' +
            ", id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", eventDate='" + eventDate + '\'' +
            ", sendDate='" + sendDate + '\'' +
            ", actionCallInfo='" + actionCallInfo + '\'' +
            ", activityRepCallInfo='" + activityRepCallInfo + '\'' +
            ", accountEPKId='" + accountEPKId + '\'' +
            ", accountCRMId='" + accountCRMId + '\'' +
            ", сallId='" + сallId + '\'' +
            ", calledFromNum='" + calledFromNum + '\'' +
            ", appealName='" + appealName + '\'' +
            ", callbackPhone='" + callbackPhone + '\'' +
            ", endDate='" + endDate + '\'' +
            ", comment='" + comment + '\'' +
            ", result='" + result + '\'' +
            ", creatorFullName='" + creatorFullName + '\'' +
            ", employeeId='" + employeeId + '\'' +
            ", crmccQuestionInfo='" + crmccQuestionInfo + '\'' +
            ", serviceRequestInfo='" + serviceRequestInfo + '\'' +
            ", actionMeetingInfo='" + actionMeetingInfo + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SrvPutBusinessOperationEventNf>
    <RqUID>info</RqUID>
    <RqTm>info</RqTm>
    <SPName>info</SPName>
    <SystemId>info</SystemId>
    <Method></Method>
    <Message>
        <Event>
            <BusinessProcess>info</BusinessProcess>
            <Operation>info</Operation>
            <Step>info</Step>
            <SourceModule>info</SourceModule>
            <Id>info</Id>
            <EventDate>info</EventDate>
            <SendDate>info</SendDate>
            <BusinessAttributes>
                <ActionCallInfo/>
                <ActivityRepCallInfo/>
                <CRMCCCallInfo>
                    <AccountEPKId>info</AccountEPKId>
                    <AccountCRMId>info</AccountCRMId>
                    <CallId>info</CallId>
                    <CalledFromNum>info</CalledFromNum>
                    <AppealName>info</AppealName>
                    <CallbackPhone>info</CallbackPhone>
                    <EndDate>info</EndDate>
                    <Comment>info</Comment>
                    <Result>info</Result>
                    <CreatorFullName>info</CreatorFullName>
                    <EmployeeId>info</EmployeeId>
                </CRMCCCallInfo>
                <CRMCCQuestionInfo/>
                <ServiceRequestInfo/>
                <ActionMeetingInfo/>
            </BusinessAttributes>
        </Event>
    </Message>
</SrvPutBusinessOperationEventNf>
```

I've got information in Java object only to Method XML tag, than only nulls.

Comment: What problems are you having with your current code?

Comment: And also, please show valid XML with your question, even if it is a simplified version of the real XML, it should still be valid to avoid confusion.

Comment: My problem, is that toString() of my Java Object shows null on <info4> and <info5> tags, but in XML they not empty.

Comment: Then you've got a bug in your code, and if you need help debugging it, will want to post a valid small representational XML file along with a valid [mcve] program that reproduces the problem for us. Please check out the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link as well as the [ask] link for more on what will help us to understand your question and problem and allow us to answer more easily.

Comment: Thanks for help, i edit my question with more technical details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build you class hierarchy etc message and event classes

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "SrvPutBusinessOperationEventNf")
public class BusinessOperationEvent
{
    @XmlElement(name = "RqUID")
    private String rqUID;
    @XmlElement(name = "RqTm")
    private String rqTm;
    @XmlElement(name = "sPName")
    private String sPName;
    @XmlElement(name = "SystemId")
    private String systemId;
    @XmlElement(name = "Method")
    private String method;
    @XmlElement(name = "Message")
    Message message


}
public class Message
{
    @XmlElement(name = "Event")
    Event event;
}
```

and so on

Comment: How can i unmarshall XML for several classes and make one toString() method with all information?

Comment: Trying unmarshalling this hierarchy clasess i've got java.lang.RuntimeException: Error unmarshalling XML

Comment: I used it years ago, I tried give you direction, maybe Message class should have an annotation. try find nested example. **I will delete the answer tomorrow.